# Заменить старые результаты поиска новыми

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, php7

Реализую поиск. Вот часть кода:

PHP:

```
...//Код
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
    $result_search_cat[] = array('label' => $row['title']);
}
exit( json_encode($result_search_cat) );
```

Принимаю json данные и обрабатываю их:

```
$('.category-activ-search1').on('change keyup', function() { 
      ....//Код
      success: function(res){
      var result = JSON.parse(res); 
      for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        $('.ppp').append('<div class="col-xs-12">'+result[i]['label']+'</div>');
      }
      ...//Код
   }
}
```

Вообщем вывожу массив данных в `div` с классом `.ppp`. Сейчас при каждом введенном символе добавляются результаты в `$('.ppp')`, и новые результаты постоянного добавляются в конец уже выведенных старых результатов, которые уже не удовлетворяют поиску. Подскажите, как это можно исправить.

Comment: Может добавить `$('.ppp').empty()` перед `for (var i = 0; ...`?

Comment: Помогло, огромное спасибо:)